# functional programming and logic?

Tags: functional-programming, prolog, scheme, logic

I have to solve an exercise in functional programming. I solved by iterative schemes, I want to use recursion but not knowing conversion? Can anyone help me k?

Title: N and N of the people, the things i would have done the job performance j A [i] [j]. Find the plan work assignments so that the greatest performance?

Here is code use loop circle

```
(define (Bai15 N)
(define i 0)
(define j 0)
(define k 0)
(define t 0)
(define ii 0)
(define jj 0)
(define dem 0)
(define MaTrix (make-vector N))
(define Result (make-vector N))
(define Test (make-vector N))
(define Max 0)
(display "a.Nhap ma trận X[1..N][1..N]:")
(newline)
(newline)
(while (< i N)
     (set! (vector-ref MaTrix i) (make-vector N))
     (set! i (+ i 1))
)
(set! i 0)
(while (< i N)
       (set! k (vector-ref MaTrix i))
       (while (< j N)
             (display "X[")
             (display i)
             (display "][")
             (display j)
             (display "]= ")
             (set! (vector-ref k j) (read))
             (set! j (+ j 1))
       )
       (newline)
       (set! j 0)
       (set! i (+ i 1))
 )
 (newline)
 (set! i 0)
 (set! j 0)
 (while (< i N)
        (set! k (vector-ref MaTrix i))
        (while (< j N)
               (display (vector-ref k j))
               (display " ")
               (set! j (+ j 1))
        )
        (newline)
        (set! j 0)
        (set! i (+ i 1))
  )

  (set! i 0)
  (while (< i N)
        (set! (vector-ref Result i) -1)
        (set! i (+ i 1))
  )
  (set! i 0)
  (while (< i N)
         (set! (vector-ref Test i) -1)
         (set! i (+ i 1))
  )
  (set! i 0)
  (while (< i N)
         (display (vector-ref Test i))
         (set! i (+ i 1))
  )
  (newline)
  (set! k 0)
  (set! i 0)
  (set! j 0)
  (set! t 0)
  (set! dem 0)

  (while (< t N)
      (if (and (not (= t 0)) (= i 0))
         (set! jj t)
         (set! jj 0))
     (while (>= (vector-ref Test jj) 0)
            (set! jj (+ jj 1))
     )
     (display "jj: ")
     (display jj)
     (newline)
     (display "i: ")
     (display i)
     (newline)
     (set! k (+ (vector-ref (vector-ref MaTrix i) jj) k))
     (display "k: ")
     (display k)
     (newline)
     (set! (vector-ref Test jj) i)
     (set! ii 0)
     (display "Test: ")
     (while (< ii N)
            (display (vector-ref Test ii))
            (display " ")
            (set! ii (+ ii 1))
     )
     (newline)
     (set! dem (+ dem 1))
     (if (= dem N)
         (begin
           (if (> k Max)
            (begin
               (set! Max k)
               (display "Max: ")
               (display Max)
               (newline)
               (set! ii 0)
               (display "Result: ")
               (while (< ii N)
                      (set! (vector-ref Result ii) (vector-ref Test ii))
                      (display (vector-ref Result ii))
                      (display " ")
                      (set! ii (+ ii 1))
                )
               (newline)
               (set! i 0)
               (while (< i N)
                      (set! (vector-ref Test i) -1)
                      (set! i (+ i 1))
                )
                (set! i 0)
                (set! dem 0)
                (set! k 0)
                (set! t (+ t 1))))
          (begin
           (set! i 0)
               (while (< i N)
                      (set! (vector-ref Test i) -1)
                      (set! i (+ i 1))
                )
                (set! i 0)
                (set! dem 0)
                (set! k 0)
                (set! t (+ t 1))))
         (begin
          (set! i (+ i 1))
          ))
  )
  (newline)
  (display "Divide the work plan: ")
  (newline)
  (set! i 0)
  (while (< i N)
       (display "Job ")
       (display (+ i 1))
       (display " - People ")
       (display (+ (vector-ref Result i) 1))
       (display " work")
       (newline)
       (set! i (+ i 1))
  )
  (display "Effective: ")
  (display Max)                                 
 )
```

I want to solve with recursion and logic programming

Comment: I think there may be some mistranslation in your description of the problem, as this sentence doesn't make any sense: "Title: N and N of the people, the things i would have done the job performance j A [i] [j]." Perhaps a longer description would translate more clearly?

Comment: This looks mostly like a line-by-line translation of another program. "A determined programmer can write Fortran in any language" -- Ed Post.

Answer (score 1):

Learning a completely new language (I.e. Haskell ([SASL dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#SASL_Based)) or Scheme ([Lisp dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#Lisp_based)) if you know Java ([Algol dialect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#ALGOL_based))) is harder than learning a new dialect of the same language family (I.e. learning Ruby when you know Java or Common Lisp if you know Scheme)

It seems you have proven it's true that you can write [Fortran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generational_list_of_programming_languages#Fortran_based) in any language.

`while` doesn't exist in Scheme, but since I also program Algol dialects I know how it's supposed to work. I guess it's definition is something like:

```scm
(define-syntax while 
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ expr body ...)
     (let loop () 
       (cond (expr body ... (loop)) 
             (else 'undefined-return))))))
```

Also your code has lots of `(set! (vector-ref ...) new-value)` which doesn't work. After fixing this the code still didn't work.

It's not trivial to just transform a project to be functional. It's far easier to start with a problem and begin dividing it in parts using divide and conquer. Not all your code can be functional because that implies you cannot have output nor input. Instead you try keeping `display` and `read` in it's own procedures.

Using arrays are a means of optimization. By design they are not functional in Scheme. A functional array would produce a new array and leaving the old as it was when changing elements. I know Racket has arrays like that but not Scheme. It's better if you recuse lists instead.

The pattern you have in your code you initialize a counter with `define` and increment it's global value in `while` while checking for a certain limit. For this you can use named `let` eg. in this code that makes list of list.

```scm
(define N 10)
(define init-list (let zero-loop ((n N) (acc '()))
                    (if (zero? n)
                        acc ; return the accumulated list
                        (zero-loop (- n 1) (cons 0 acc))))) ; ==> undefine, init-list is (0 0 ...) 

(let lol ((n N)) (acc '())
  (if (zero? n)
      acc
      (lol (- n 1) (cons init-list acc)))) ; ==> ((0 0 0...) ...)
```

I'm unsure what you program is supposed to do so I'll stop here. You have to start writing Scheme in Scheme. If you are having problems with this you should begin with a tutorial. Perhaps follow the [SICP video](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/) lectures or if you really want to be good, finish the [SICP books exercises](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/). In the video lectures you learn how to make a programming language like Prolog.